# Failed to connect to PC-Name\SQLEXPRESS - Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server database via node.js (Express), but the connection cannot be established. The connection is successfully connected via SQL Server Management Studio, but through my code, it is not.

Please check my connection code:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');

var serviceName = 'DESKTOP-877085U\\SQLEXPRESS'
console.log(serviceName);
class DBConnection {
async getConnection() {
   try {
     return await mssql.connect({
            user: 'mj',
            password: 'mj',
            server: serviceName,
            database: 'DemoDb',
            port: 1433,
            trustServerCertificate: true,
     });
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
}
module.exports = new DBConnection();
```

Once I run the application via CMD, it took less than one minute, and this error appeared:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-877085U\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
>
> at C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17
> at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:844:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:965:18)
> at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1194:10)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1139:12)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
> code: 'ETIMEOUT',
> originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-877085U\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
> at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1194:26)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1139:12)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
> code: 'ETIMEOUT',
> isTransient: undefined
> }
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
>
> at ProductMSSql.getAllProducts (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\modules\Product\product.mssql.js:5:28)
> at async getAllProducts (C:\Users\mo7am\Downloads\Projects\nodejs-sqlserver2\modules\Product\product.js:5:25)

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try options like:

```
".\SQLEXPRESS"
or
"localhost"
```

Or try to find out what is the host name like below:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks, adding "localhost" is fixing my issue.